# Add custom logic/callback/handler when EOF for JsonFraming in akka-streams

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream

I have a flow where I consume the paths to the files in small batches from Kafka pah topics, read the files themselves(big JSON arrays) and write them back to Kafka data topics.

It looks like this:

```
      val fileFlow = Flow[Path].flatMapConcat(HdfsSource.data(fs, _))
        .via(JsonFraming.objectScanner(Int.MaxValue))

      Consumer
        .committableSource(newConsumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(inputTopicNames))
        .map(value => value)
        .grouped(kafkaConsumerBatch)
        .flatMapConcat(paths => Source(paths))
        .map(path => new Path(path.record.value().get("fullPath").asInstanceOf[String]))
        //Based on: https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/v3.0.0/doc-examples/src/test/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/eip/scaladsl/PassThroughExamples.scala#L72-L92
        .via(PassThroughFlow(fileFlow))
        .map { case (bytes, path) => (bytes, entityConfigMap(getCountryPrefix(path))) }
        .map(bytesAndPath => (bytesAndPath._1.utf8String.parseJson.asJsObject, bytesAndPath._2))
        .map { case (bytes, entityConfig) => (toGenericRecord(bytes, entityConfig), entityConfig) }
        .map { case (record, entityConfig) =>
          producerMessagesToTopic.mark()
          ProducerMessage.single(
            new ProducerRecord[NotUsed, GenericRecord](getDataTopicName(entityConfig), record),
            passThrough = entityConfig)
        }
        .via {
          akka.kafka.scaladsl.Producer.flexiFlow(prodSettings)
        }
....More logic for logging and running/materializing the flow
```

Now, the problem is that, as I said, those JSON files are big, so I can't take the entire file content, frame it into separate objects, store them all to Kafka and commit only after that. I mean, that's what I need to do, but I also  need to control the offset commit based on the EOF event.

I want to let Producer send data over to Kafka in its own pace and regardless of its configs, but somehow inject my custom logic into an EOF event. Maybe something like a passThrough field to signify that the file has been fully consumed and we can now commit offset for the upstream path topic.
`objectScanner` has a `GraphStageLogic` inside its definition that has `onUpstreamFinish` callback, but there's no direct access to it for overriding. And classes like `SimpleLinearGraphStage`, `JsonObjectParser` are marked as Internal APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struck by

> ...I can't take the entire file content, frame it into separate objects, store them all to Kafka and commit only after that

Since it seems (and you can comment if I'm getting this wrong) that the offset commit is effectively an acknowledgement that you've fully processed a file, there's no way around not committing the offset until after all the objects in the file in the message at that offset have been produced to Kafka.

The downside of `Source.via(Flow.flatMapConcat.via(...)).map.via(...)` is that it's a single stream and everything between the first and second `via`s, inclusive takes a while.

If you're OK with interleaving objects from files in the output topic and are OK with an unavoidable chance of an object from a given file being produced twice to the output topic (both of these may or may not impose meaningful constraints/difficulties on the implementation of downstream consumers of that topic), you can parallelize the processing of a file.  The `mapAsync` stream stage is especially useful for this:

```
import akka.Done

// assuming there's an implicit Materializer/ActorSystem (depending on the version of Akka Streams you're running) in scope
def process(path: Path): Future[Done] =
  Source.single(path)
    .via(PassThroughFlow(fileFlow))
    .map { case (bytes, path) => (bytes, entityConfigMap(getCountryPrefix(path))) }
    .map(bytesAndPath => (bytesAndPath._1.utf8String.parseJson.asJsObject, bytesAndPath._2))
    .map { case (bytes, entityConfig) => (toGenericRecord(bytes, entityConfig), entityConfig) }
    .map { case (record, entityConfig) =>
      producerMessagesToTopic.mark()
      ProducerMessage.single(
        new ProducerRecord[NotUsed, GenericRecord](getDataTopicName(entityConfig), record),
        passThrough = entityConfig)
    }
    .via {
      akka.kafka.scaladsl.Producer.flexiFlow(prodSettings)
    }
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)

 // then starting right after .flatMapConcat(paths => Source(paths))
 .mapAsync(parallelism) { committableMsg =>
   val p = new Path(committableMsg.record.value().get("fullPath").asInstanceOf[String])
   process(p).map { _ => committableMsg.committableOffset }
 }
 // now have the committable offsets
```

`parallelism` then limits how many paths you're processing at a given time.  Ordering into the committer is maintained (i.e. an offset never reaches the committer before all messages before it have been fully processed).

Comment: I'm going to re-phrase it, Levi. What I meant is that I can't hold the entire file content in producer's buffer because those are Datalake files and they can exceed 100M easily. So, I need to store the offset only when the file is fully processed, but I need a way to split the content of the file in chunks and then figure out how to expose and handle the EOF event so as to store the offset. The chunks split might work out of the box with what KafkaProducer provides but I can't find anything for the EOF handling.

Comment: With mine, you get the EOF event from the fact that the stream completes (which completes the `Future`), since instead of concating the stream from the `HdfsSource` to the overall stream (thus throwing away the stream completion), we're running each file as its own stream.

Comment: Whether the `HdfsSource` eagerly reads everything into memory or not, I don't know, but that's not the question you were asking.

Comment: Confirmed from docs, `HdfsSource` only reads 8k at a time.

Comment: Levi, it's an amazing idea. I will try to re-write my code tomorrow and provide further feedback! Thanks!

Comment: Also, Levi, can you elaborate on "unavoidable chance of an object from a given file being produced twice to the output topic"? How does async uncoupling increase that chance?

Comment: There was a chance of that happening in the non-async implementation as well.  Basically, because we don't commit the offset until we've fully processed the file, but are producing in a streaming fashion, if there's an interruption (e.g. a failure, or the service gets stopped), the stream will resume from the last committed offset and produce the objects that it had produced between the last offset commit and when it stopped.  The approach of committing offsets after completely processing is an "at-least-once" approach (committing the offset and then producing is, conversely, "at-most-once")

Comment: Increasing the parallelism increases the amount of work that's in flight and also introduces the possibility that every object in a source file gets produced multiple times.  This is because the `mapAsync` stage will not emit the result (`Done`) of a future until all futures before that were emitted (that is to say, it preserves order).  So if file A is before file B, file B completes, then file A fails, file B's offset will not be committed (to do so would mean that file A never gets completely processed).  On resumption, file A and file B will be reprocessed.